# Using DispatchGroup within multiple for loop - Swift & Firebase

Tags: swift, firebase, swift3

I'm having an issue with getting dispatchgroup functions to work when combined with multiple for loops. In my code below, my first dispatch pulls in the coauthorId field for each of the coauthorID under my userId.

I'm getting an error when the code reaches the first dispatchgroup.leave() function so I'm not sure if it has something to do with where the dispatchgroup functions are placed.

Datebase structure:

```
posts
  --ABC //my userId
    --XXX //coauthorId
      --coauthorId: XXX
    --ZZZ //coauthorId
      --coauthorId: ZZZ
  --YYY //coauthorId
      --coauthorId: YYY
```

Code:

```
    var ListA = [String]()
    var ListB = [String]()

    func fetchPosts() {

    let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()

    let currentUser = Auth.auth().currentUser!

    dispatchGroup.enter() 
    Database.database().reference().child("posts").child(currentUser.uid).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot : DataSnapshot) in

        // Iterate through all the children:

        for child in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {

            let value = child.value as? NSDictionary

            let coauthorId = value?["coauthorId"] as? String ?? ""
         Database.database().reference().child("posts").child(coauthorId).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot : DataSnapshot) in

                // Iterate through all the children:

                for child1 in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {

                    let value1 = child1.value as? NSDictionary

                    let coauthorId1 = value1?["coauthorId"] as? String ?? ""

                    self.ListA.append(coauthorId1)

                    dispatchGroup.leave() //this is where I get an error

                }
            })

        }

    })

            dispatchGroup.enter()

    //fetches the Id of my posts

    Database.database().reference().child("posts").child(currentUser.uid).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot : DataSnapshot) in

        // Iterate through all the children:

        for child in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {
            // Add the user ID to the array:

            let value = child.value as? NSDictionary

            let mycoauthorId = value?["coauthorId"] as? String ?? ""

            self.ListB.append(mycoauthorId)

        }
        dispatchGroup.leave()
    })

    // Notify the dispatch group:

    dispatchGroup.notify(queue: DispatchQueue.main, execute: {

        // Now that both completion blocks (from your two observers) ran, combine both arrays

        let combinedArray = self.ListA + self.ListB
        print(combinedArray)

        })
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: The error I'm getting is "Thread1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION..."

Comment: Does anyone have an idea how to solve this?

Comment: Why are you doing this? You're wrapping asynchronous code around asynchronous code, and stacking Dispatches needlessly. Also, you're calling *dispatchGroup.leave()* before the loop has completed in one case and then after in another. Can you clarify the question? i.e. 'I want to load posts into one array and then post authors into another' The comments on your Firebase structure don't make a lot of sense and you have two different descriptions for parent nodes (ABC & YYY); please include a snippet of your actual structure (Firebase console->Export JSON) as text with accurate comments

Comment: Also, there's probably no reason to use an id as the parent key of a node and then also store it in a value of a child node. For example, YYY is the parent and then is also the value of coauthor:id. It's best practice to use childByAutoId to create the parent keys and then store the users uid (or author id etc) as the value of the child node.